# Converting Pi Into Letters?

Tags: java, numbers

For Pi Day, I am trying to write a Java program that tries to find a given word in Pi (or another given irrational number). I almost have it all completed, but I am conflicted about how I should convert each digit/digits of pi into a letter. I thought of saying: A=01, B=02, C=03...Y=25, Z=26.

However, I then felt bad for all the poor number sequences that don't even have a chance since any sequence that does not begin with a "0" or "2" will be disregarded entirely. This means 80% of sequences are irrelevant?

Can I do a base-26 to base-10 conversion? Not sure how to do that code-wise if that is indeed a proper solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You could always check single-digits *and* valid two-digit numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert Pi from its base-10 form to any other base (i.e. base 26, where you only use letters A-Z, and not numbers 0-9), using a method [like this one](http://javaconfessions.com/2008/09/convert-between-base-10-and-base-62-in_28.html). The resulting "digits" will be all letters.

You'll have to modify the `fromDecimalToOtherBase` method so that it only outputs letters. Otherwise, it should be pretty straight forward, and it's the same algorithm to convert between decimal and any arbitrary base.

Just for kicks, I also found [this page](http://www.convertit.com/go/convertit/calculators/math/base_converter.asp) which contains an arbitrary base converter. If you enter Pi without the decimal, and enter "26" for the destination base, it'll do the conversion (though it still uses digits 0-9, so it doesn't "solve" the problem, the way you want to).

Comment: I think I will just convert the numbers to letters using your method, then see if it contains a word. Is there a Java method to find a string within a string? I guess I will find out!? Thanks all! :)

Comment: This should get you started, though it may not be the most efficient way to search for substrings, and depending on how many digits of pi you're using and the length of your dictionary or words, it might take quite a long time to run: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/SearchString.html

Comment: Doesn't String.indexOf() have a worst behavior of O(N)? I just want to find the first instance of a given word. I am currently using 100K digits of pi and tau. It didn't take too long to read in the file to an array, so I think I should be ok time wise.

Comment: Yeah it's probably not very efficient. If this isn't a mission critical app, I'm guessing you either don't care in this case, or you'll use it as an exercise to find a better, faster way.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the alphabet wrap around and use all codes.

```
00 = A
01 = B
...
24 = Y
25 = Z
26 = A
27 = B
...
```

Or, why bother with base 10 at all? Just express the number in base 26 to start with, and each digit represents a letter.

```
pi = D,DRSQLOLYRTRCLRGGUKBJKPSRFVKRODHLJRFSZSOXNHXZ...
```